# Converted from a basic disk to a dynamic drive in Boot Camp

Tags: partition

I got a MacBook Pro and installed Windows 10 using Boot Camp and all was fine. I then needed to create a 50GB NTFS partition, when Windows prompted me to convert to a dynamic disk, I mistakenly hit enter.

When I rebooted PC, the Mac option was gone. Could you please help me to restore my Mac partition and data?

Comment: This is unlikely to be a simple fix. If you have backups, then just wipe it all & start over. Otherwise, have a look at this - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/224702/accidentaly-converted-from-a-basic-disk-to-a-dynamic-one? Note that Windows doesn't understand how it is being 'fooled' into thinking it is in charge; never let anything adjust partitions from inside Boot Camp.

Answer (score -1):

Multiple people have hit the exact same issue that you described. As per [Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/basic-and-dynamic-disks), other operating systems like macOS and Linux do not understand Dynamic Disks.

Fortunately, what you did can be reverted. It's not straightforward, but it is 100% possible using the open-source utility named [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). Do try it out -- there's some pain involved, but it will be worth the result.