# How to add a disk to the Win10 on the Mac?

Tags: mac, windows

I used Boot Camp to create a Win10 system on my Mac 2017.

[image]

But you see the C disk only 37.8G usable (40G), how can I divide a disk from the Mac to add a D disk to the Win10 system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things to consider...

- Do you have sufficient spare drive space on your Mac drive?
- Do you really need a separate partition or just a larger C partition?
- The only Apple-supported way to change the size of a Boot Camp partition is to delete it then re-add from Boot Camp Assistant - not great if you need to preserve data on the Windows partition.
- Disk Utility will not allow you to create more than 4 partitions on a drive, including hidden partitions. The Boot Camp partition was already the fourth.
- Trying to change partitions in any way, shape or form from inside Windows will break your entire Mac/Win drive structure.

The only application I know of that can move, create, resize, backup partitions, including Boot Camp, without breaking anything is [Paragon Hard Disk Manager](https://www.paragon-software.com/home/hdm-mac/)
My recommendation would be to use it to increase the size of the C partition [thereby shrinking the Mac partition, assuming sufficient free space] rather than create another as a D partition.

Comment: Yes, I did that, so I can not boot the mac os now. Get C and D partition.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/222769/missing-mac-partitions-unrecognized-file-system for the potential fix if you used Windows to adjust the partitions. Post a new question if that doesn't help. [klanomath](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/93229/klanomath) is one of the very few people who knows how to do this type of reconstruction.