# How do I regain all unallocated disk space to add it to macOS after removing Linux partitions?

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition, ssd

I originally came across [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/262042/partition-on-hfs-external-drive-invalid-number-of-allocation-blocks-file-sy) with a possible answer but, I do not understand how to go about the process, especially when 2 drives are both not showing there full size. This originally happened when I had Ubuntu Gnome installed alongside OS X (one drive (SSD)).
  I have dedicated the SSD to my OSes and the other HDD to my home folders.

When I attempted to delete the Linux partitons (one on each drive) they are now completely gone out of sight. I am unable to regain that space to add it to my system and home partiton on the drives.

Both are 500 GB drives but only 250 GB are used. I have a mid 2012 MacPro

(Incase your wondering how I have 2 drives in this mac I replaced my optical drive with a hard drive caddy)

When trying to read the gtp/pmbr scheme this is what it spits out
disk0 is osx disk1 is home.

```
  zackerys-MacBook-Pro:~ gefiltefish1478$ sudo gpt show disk1
Password:
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  488050672      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  488460312       2024         
  488462336     260096      3  GPT part - 0657FD6D-A4AB-43C4-84E5-0933C84B4F4F
  488722432  487790592         
  976513024     260096      4  GPT part - 0657FD6D-A4AB-43C4-84E5-0933C84B4F4F
  976773120         15         
  976773135         32         Sec GPT table
  976773167          1         Sec GPT header
zackerys-MacBook-Pro:~ gefiltefish1478$ sudo gpt show disk0
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640   499902768      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   500312408     1269536      3  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
   501581944   498372488         
   999954432      260096      4  GPT part - 0657FD6D-A4AB-43C4-84E5-0933C84B4F4F
  1000214528         655         
  1000215183          32         Sec GPT table
  1000215215           1         Sec GPT header
```

[image: disk1]

[image: and both drives show somthing like this]

This is the output when I run `df`.

```
df
Filesystem                       512-blocks      Used Available Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2                      499902768 130185800 369204968    27% 1249077 4293718202    0%   /
devfs                                   375       375         0   100%     651          0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk1s2                      488050672 465813600  22237072    96%   89020 4294878259    0%   /Volumes/HOME
map -hosts                                0         0         0   100%       0          0  100%   /net
map auto_home                             0         0         0   100%       0          0  100%   /home
localhost:/KJdZJAu-3rlfljye4LGYtx 499902768 499902768         0   100%       0          0  100%   /Volumes/MobileBackups
/dev/disk1s1                         403266        15    403251     1%       0          0  100%   /private/var/tmp/MP4XJX8Y
```

I'm extremely wary about rewriting any GPT without someone else's input. 
Needing help; I know @klanomath was able to fix this issue hopefully he can have some input on my situation.  Possibly someone can make a bash command line to automate the process for other users who may encounter the issue.

Possible future GitHub project if I figure out how to do this on my own.

Comment: This question is very difficult to read.  Can you please add some punctuation and adjust the formatting?  That will help people understand your issue and try to suggest fixes.

Comment: @fsb Yes, my apologies. I have edited it; in desperate need of help.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Disk0s3 has the wrong partition type: it should be 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC. Everything else looks ok. To regain empty and continuous space to expand your OS X partitions you simply have to delete disk1s3 and disk1s4 as well as disk0s4 (all Linux remnants).

Comment: @klanomath Ive tried deleting the partitions (in osx and recovery) but i get
"MediaKit reports partition (map) too small. If you recently grew your whole-disk, you should run whole-disk repair." On disk0 and "Couldn’t read partition map." on disk1. Is there any other data I could post to help diagnose the issue.

Comment: @klanomath Im thinking it would be possible to boot into gparted and deleting those partitions since I have an ISO on hand.

Comment: @NEXTCODE4U Did you soft link the whole /Users folder to /Volumes/HOME (disk0s2) or single $user folders to /Volumes/HOME/Users/$user (or /Volumes/HOME/$user)?

Comment: @NEXTCODE4U gparted is IMHO always a very bad idea! You can regain the space and change the Recovery HD's type in Internet Recovery Mode or with a bootable OS X installer thumb drive (depends on your Mac model)!

Comment: @klanomath Its single; just my user folder. Ive had the home folder like this even before I installed ubuntu so i don't see how it could be part of the issue. BTW thanks for the input more than appreciate it. I'm desperate for my storage!!!

Comment: @NEXTCODE4U there are several methods to "export" a user folder: 1. soft link to /Users/ or changing the $user folder to /Volumes/HOME/ with dscl (or with the Directory Tool) or in the system prefs > User & Groups. Do you still have a /Users folder in the root directory? I'm just asking for safety nets (e.g. if you have a second admin user at /Users/$adminuser2) Depending on that I'll propose a strategy how to resolve your problem.

Comment: @klanomath I did it through system prefrences

Comment: @NEXTCODE4U Also: Please add your Mac model to the question (e.g. MacBook Pro Early 2011 or MacBook late 2009)

Comment: @klanomath YOU WERE RIGHT! I have a mid 2012 mac pro so it would only let me use the mountain lion recovery (witch wouldn't let me delete the partitions) I simply partitioned a section of my drive and wrote the sierra installer to it. (sorry didn't know i had a copy in my home folder) After deleting all linux partitions and my recovery partition I was able to reclaim my space. I see where I went wrong now, my bad. More than appreciate the input. I wouldn't of been able to figure it out without ya homie -hits my chest twice and throws peace sign-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your disk contains some blocking Linux swap partitions: disk1s3, disk1s4 and disk0s4 (all partitions with the type 0657FD6D-A4AB-43C4-84E5-0933C84B4F4F). Additionally your probable Recovery HD disk0s3 has the wrong type: it should be 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC.

Depending on your Mac model either use Internet Recovery Mode or a bootable OS X installer thumb drive to "repair" your disks.

---

Since your user folder resides on a different partition create a *safety net* admin user first on your boot disk. Log-in as second admin user to be sure that the account works independently from your main admin user.

---

- Boot to Internet Recovery Mode (or the thumb drive)
- Open Terminal in the menubar > Utilities
- Enter `diskutil list` to get an overview.
- Use the disk identifiers of your SSD and the HDD (e.g disk0 and disk1) enter `gpt -r show disk$`.

  Below I assume disk0 is your system disk and disk1 is your HOME disk.
- Unmount both disks with `diskutil umountDisk disk0`and  `diskutil umountDisk disk1`.
- remove the two swap partitions on disk1:

  ```
  gpt remove -i 3 disk1
  diskutil umountDisk disk1
  gpt remove -i 4 disk1
  ```
- remove the Recovery HD and the swap partitions on disk1:

  ```
  gpt remove -i 3 disk0
  diskutil umountDisk disk0
  gpt remove -i 4 disk0
  diskutil umountDisk disk0
  ```
- re-add the Recovery HD with the proper type:

  ```
  gpt add -i 3 -b 500312408 -s 1269536 -t 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk0
  ```
- resize both main volumes with:

  ```
  diskutil resizeVolume /dev/disk0s2 100%
  diskutil resizeVolume /dev/disk1s2 100%
  ```
- Verify both volumes with `diskutil verifyVolume disk0s2` and  `diskutil verifyVolume disk1s2`. If necessary repair the volumes.
- Reboot