# Invalid number of allocation blocks in Disk Utility Repair

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

First of all I hope @klanomath is still active over here as I'm having a similar issue as described in following thread: [Partition on HFS+ external drive: "Invalid number of allocation blocks", file system check exit code 8. Unable to repair, even in recovery mode](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/262042/partition-on-hfs-external-drive-invalid-number-of-allocation-blocks-file-sy/350846#350846) .
However it's slightly different.

I'm having the "invalid number of allocation blocks" error on my main hard drive (startup disk).

As it looks like the solution for this issue was "tailor-made" for the problem of the initial poster I'd like to ask if you could adapt the solution for my case.

Which info would you need and would you be able to repair the disk so no data would be lost. I've been hard at work just before my crash and it would take a lot of time to do it all again. Sadly my NAS wasn't available at the time for a Time Machine backup...

I also checked this [HFS+ invalid number of allocation blocks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/176777/hfs-invalid-number-of-allocation-blocks?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I don't really understand what's going on there and I don't want to do anything wrong.

Let's hope someone can help me!

Thanks in advance!

Kindest regards,

Kim

Edit:

```
-bash-3.2# diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Naamloos                499.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +2.1 GB     disk1
   1:                  Apple_HFS OS X Base System        2.0 GB     disk1s1

/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +5.2 MB     disk2

/dev/disk3 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk3

/dev/disk4 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk4

/dev/disk5 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk5

/dev/disk6 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk6

/dev/disk7 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk7

/dev/disk8 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk8

/dev/disk9 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +12.6 MB    disk9

/dev/disk10 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +4.2 MB     disk10

/dev/disk11 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk11

/dev/disk12 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk12

/dev/disk13 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk13

/dev/disk14 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk14

/dev/disk15 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +1.0 MB     disk15

/dev/disk16 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +6.3 MB     disk16

/dev/disk17 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +6.3 MB     disk17

/dev/disk18 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +524.3 KB   disk18

/dev/disk19 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            untitled               +2.1 MB     disk19

-bash-3.2# df
Filesystem   512-blocks    Used Available Capacity iused      ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1s1    3930264 2485704   1405264    64%   45155 4294922124    0%   /
devfs               395     395         0   100%     684          0  100%   /dev
/dev/disk2        10240    2232      8008    22%      23 4294967256    0%   /private/var/log
/dev/disk3         1024     288       736    29%       4 4294967275    0%   /Volumes
/dev/disk4         1024     288       736    29%       7 4294967272    0%   /private/var/tmp
/dev/disk5         1024     312       712    31%      12 4294967267    0%   /private/var/run
/dev/disk6         4096     280      3816     7%       2 4294967277    0%   /private/tmp
/dev/disk7         1024     288       736    29%       3 4294967276    0%   /System/Installation
/dev/disk8         1024     592       432    58%      21 4294967258    0%   /private/var/db
/dev/disk9        24576   10640     13936    44%      85 4294967194    0%   /private/var/folders
/dev/disk10        8192    8192         0   100%     243 4294967036    0%   /private/var/root/Library
/dev/disk12        4096     280      3816     7%       2 4294967277    0%   /private/var/root/Library/Containers
/dev/disk13        1024     360       664    36%      11 4294967268    0%   /Library/Preferences
/dev/disk14        1024     320       704    32%       6 4294967273    0%   /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration
/dev/disk15        2048     368      1680    18%       6 4294967273    0%   /Library/Keychains
/dev/disk16       12288     344     11944     3%       2 4294967277    0%   /private/var/tmp/RecoveryTemp
/dev/disk17       12288     344     11944     3%       2 4294967277    0%   /private/var/tmp/OSISPredicateUpdateProductTemp
/dev/disk18        1024     280       744    28%       2 4294967277    0%   /private/var/tmp/InstallerCookies
/dev/disk19        4096     280      3816     7%       2 4294967277    0%   /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports
/dev/disk0s3    1269536 1046120    210728    84%      19 4294967260    0%   /Volumes/Image Volume
```

Comment: It would help, if you could post the output from `diskutil list` and `df`. These commands will not change your computer. You will need to enter the commands in a Terminal application window. Edit your question and paste the output. Don't worry about the format, someone else edit your question and fix this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is that I can't copy anything from the terminal as I only can get into recovery mode. Or is there another option? Like SSH into recovery mode from another device?

Comment: You should be able copy from the Terminal application and paste into Safari while in recovery mode.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know there was a browser available. I've edited the output into the main post.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I just found out my TimeMachine did run just before the crash so I could just do a clean install + restore. Or do you think the issue will remain and have to be fixed first?